# How do we solve these permutation and combination questions?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Q1 In how many ways a panel of six doctors is selected from five surgeons and six physicians if condition is surgeons are more than physicians.
A 82   B 81    C 65    D 135

Q2 Find the no. of sequences in which seven players can throw a ball,so that the youngest player is not the last.
a 4000   b 2160    c 4320    d 5300

Q3 Ways of choosing two white squares in same row or column on an 8*8 chessboard-

a 12    b 96   c 48    d 60

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. How far have you got? Q1 What are the possibilities for the number of surgeons? How many ways if you have 5 surgeons and 1 physician?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have 4 or 5 surgeons among the 6 in the panel. Count these separately. The order does not matter, so we can pick the 4 surgeons in ${5 \choose 4}$ ways followed by ${6 \choose 2}$ ways to pick 2 physicians. Add this to ${5 \choose 5}{6 \choose 1}$ ways to pick all 5 surgeons and 1 physician. The correct answer is not among your answers, BTW, unless you modify a digit..

How many sequences of throws are there in total? Substract all sequences where the youngest throws last, which is essentially all orders with 6 players (as one has a fixed place).

How many rows are there? Then for a fixed row we pick we pick 2 out of 4 (no order) of the white squares in how many ways? Then do the same for columns. (Or the first number times 2).